# AW Snap! Google chrome, out of memory while trying to display web page, but the same page with same content was working fine earlier

Tags: c#, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Suddenly my web application started displaying Aw Snap error in google chrome but the same content is displaying earlier versions of chrome.

Can some body help me out with this issue, we are using Angular JS

Working version in chrome- 102.X
Current version in chrome- 105.X (Not working)

Comment: The webpage is using the same amount of memory.  The extra memory is being used before the call.  The new version of Chrome is probably using more memory and you were always just on the edge of running out of memory.  The problem may not be Chrome itself and may be due to your machine using memory before call.  Use Task Manager to verify exactly were all the memory is being used.